# RHEL9 - VSCode: issue with wildcard in workspace folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, rhel

I am using a set up with following versions:

- RHEL 9.2
- G++ 11.4.1
- GCC 11.4.1
- VSCode 1.86.2

I am trying to compile a C++ project but I am getting the error:

```
 /usr/bin/g++ -g -std=c++20 '/home/cg/Desktop/cppproject/43IntegerTypes/*.cpp' -o /home/cg/Desktop/cppproject/43IntegerTypes/rooster
cc1plus: fatal error: /home/cg/Desktop/cppproject/43IntegerTypes/*.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

My tasks.json file looks like the following:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "build with GCC",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-std=c++20",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/rooster"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

if I change the line from `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"` to `"${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp"`, then the program is compiled without errors.

Is there any issue with my setup and the wildcard?

Comment: No its a recent bug in the c++ extension.